# copy or transfer document between two different aws s3 account

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to transfer a file from b1 bucket aws s3 account 1 to b2 bucket aws s3 account 2.
Is there a way to doing this using aws php sdk.
please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have cross account IAM/Policy defined and then have lambda (or) CLI (or) SDK for whatever operations you would like to perform on the resources.

Here is an [tutorial provided AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html) on how to configure cross account IAM for S3 access.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, instructions to copy objects in Amazon S3 using PHP can be found here: [Copy an Object Using the AWS SDK for PHP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectUsingPHP.html)

This command also works between buckets -- even buckets in different regions.

Then, to add the requirement of copying objects between accounts:

- Invoke the copy command with credentials from the **receiving account** (This helps setup default permissions. If you do it the other way, be sure to set `ACL` to `bucket-owner-full-control`.)
- You need to grant access to the object. So, if you are copying with credentials from the receiving account, you must **grant access to the receiving account**.

This can best be done in the **Bucket Policy** on the originating bucket, such as this:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "arn:aws:iam::RECEIVING-ACCOUNT-ID:user/USERNAME",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Bottom line:** Grant access to the objects, then copy the objects!

Answer (score 1):

So yeah, three years after the OP.  But hey, maybe this will help someone - as the other answers didn't quite do it for me.

This URl helped a bunch: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/

I set up the mentioned bucket policy on the source bucket in Account A:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountB_ID:user/AccountB_UserName"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ReplicateObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::AccountA_BucketName/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

NOTE: that ACCOUNTB_ID is the "AWS account ID" for AccountB.  I found mine in the IAM Management Console - Bottom of left side navigation pane

I then set a policy on AccountB_Username whose credential I was using in my PHP

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ReplicateObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::AccountA_BucketName/*"
         }
    ]
}
```

Lastly, since the Buckets were in different regions, i needed to use a MultiRegionClient in my PHP.

```
$s3Client  = new \Aws\S3\S3MultiRegionClient($options);
```

Then used

```
$s3Client->copyObject([
                'Bucket'     => $destBucket,
                'Key'        => $destKey,
                'CopySource' => "{$srcBucket}/{$srcKey}",
            ]);)
```

HTH.